# Linux command to list the file names which have numbers?

Tags: linux

I have 50000 files html files on my linux work station. Some of them contain phone numbers. Is there any linux command to list all the files that contain phone numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it the simple way with **character classes** in bash:

```
ls -al *[0-9]*
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the file contains phone number in file name, I think you can use

```
ls | egrep "[0-9]{11}"
```

If you mean the file contains phone number in content, use

```
egrep -r  "([0-9]){11}"
```